Is there a way to use fill items in a bslib sidebar?
I can't find a way to use fill items in a bslib sidebar.
In this case I am trying to put an element in the bottom of the sidebar.
layout_sidebar is fillable, but only the main area is fillable.
This puts properly the top and bottom elements in the main area:
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fillable(
  layout_sidebar(
    # sidebar = sidebar(
      card(
        fill = TRUE,
        fillable = TRUE,
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("top")
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = TRUE
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("bottom")
        )
      )
    # )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Fillable main area:

I would like to have the same behavior in the sidebar.
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fillable(
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      fillable = TRUE,
      card(
        fill = TRUE,
        fillable = TRUE,
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("top")
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = TRUE
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("bottom")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Non fillable sidebar:

I tried using as_fill_carrier() on the sidebar but it returns this warning:
Warning: `bindFillRole()` only works on htmltools::tag() objects 
(e.g., div(), p(), etc.), not objects of type 'bslib_sidebar'.


The relevant part of the DOM here looks like this (aside > .sidebar-content > bslib::card()):
<aside id="bslib-sidebar-5784" class="sidebar" hidden>
  <div class="sidebar-content bslib-gap-spacing">
    <div class="card bslib-card bslib-mb-spacing html-fill-item html-fill-container" 
         data-bslib-card-init data-require-bs-caller="card()" data-require-bs-version="5">
      ...

From the card on the setup is suitable. What you need to add is (see also the article on Filling layouts in the bslib docs):

the html-fill-container class to the sidebar-content,
the html-fill-item class to the sidebar-content,
the html-fill-container class to the aside (.sidebar).

Below this is implemented via htmltools::tagQuery().

library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fillable(
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      card(
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("top")
        ),
        card_body(),
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("bottom")
        )
      )
    ) 
  ) 
)

ui <- htmltools::tagQuery(ui)$
  find("aside")$
  addClass("html-fill-container")$
  find(".sidebar-content")$
  addClass("html-fill-container html-fill-item")$
  allTags()

shinyApp(ui, \(...){})


Here is what I think you are looking for in your sidebar:
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fillable(
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      fillable = TRUE,
      card(
        fill = TRUE,
        fillable = TRUE,
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("top")
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = TRUE
        ),
        card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("bottom",style = "margin-top:400px;")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

A little CSS was all that was needed to push the bottom element downwards in:
card_body(
          fill = FALSE,
          h1("bottom",style = "margin-top:400px;")
        )
      )


You can play around with the CSS margin-top parameter if you want to move the elements downwards even more.

Thanks, but I really want the sidebar to become fillable, I have a big app with several sidebars with complex structures and main areas and would like to use the same structure everywhere.
